# Google Sheet - Concatenate text with date format

Tags: google-sheets

How with Google Sheet I can concatenate text and date ?

This is what I have tried:

```
=CONCATENATE("Date : "; TEXT(C9, "YYYY-MM-DD"); ". Thanks.")
```

Output should be:

```
Date : 2023-01-03. Thanks.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the value in C9 you are using & also whats the error? care to share a screenshot or sample sheet?!

Comment: The error is 'Formula error'. In C9, I have a date like `2023-01-03`.

Comment: try: =CONCATENATE("Date :  ", TEXT(C9, "YYYY-MM-DD"), ". Thanks.")

Comment: Does it test TRUE for =ISDATE(C9)

Comment: The spreadsheet is in a locale that uses comma `,` as decimal separator. Use semicolons (;) as formula argument separators as in `text(C9; "yyyy-MM-dd")`. See [Syntax differences in formulas](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/) by Ben Collins.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the value in cell `C9` in the format it shows in the spreadsheet with the `to_text()` function, like this:

`="Date: " & to_text(C9) & ". Thanks."`